# question about other dimensions

Tags: string-theory, big-bang, spacetime-dimensions, large-hadron-collider, cosmology

The [Big Bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce) theory says that before the Big Bang there were other Big Bangs over and over. For example, the universe would have a Big Bang within it and then this new mini-universe would expand, then start collapsing, and as it finishes collapsing, it would "bounce" back into a Big Bang, while the greater universe stays constant.

Since this is a big explosion, nothing resists it, so we can't find any trace of the other universe ours started in, but would we be able to find evidence for this in the small dimensions that exist in string theory?  They're so small they would resist the Big Bang. If the LHC found these dimensions, would it confirm the theory?

Comment: 1. " there's a theory that says" what theory?
2. Can you please add a view points and make this into more then one monster sentence? I have a hard time getting the question.

Comment: Sorry, The theory is called The Big Bounce

Comment: @M.J.Steil, is the question clearer now?

Comment: It is better then before but I am afraid I have no answer for that; I know next to nothing about string theory and extra dimensions. If the LHC would really find experimental evidence or hints on extra dimensions this would certainly give a boost to the theories that predict those. I do not know if and how this Big Bounce theory is realted to string theory/ies or extra dimensions.

Comment: Thanks you very much Heather, you cleared it up, first time i asked a question si wasn't vert clear sorry

Answer (score -1):

Dimensions don't work that way. For example, the third dimension is based on an XYZ plain, the second is based on a YZ plain, and the first is on a Z plain. So the first contains speed but not velocity. Where did you learn what dimensions are anyway?

Answer (score -2):

In big bang during that point of time all the matter in this universe was concentrated in a single point like space. So the density of matter at that point of time was infinite leading to singularity and at that point of time the curvature of space and time was infinite therefore the consequences before big bang can never affect anything present after big bang in this universe. And therefore we can never find traces of the early universe in this universe irrespective of it was present or not . And this is the reason why we say that big bang was the beginning of TIME .

Comment: [The Big Bang did not happen at a point](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/50583).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Can you please elaborate what are you trying to say as I don't think anything in my answer is correct .

Comment: @ACuriousMind Can you tell theory of big bang?

Comment: I linked a very popular question about the Big Bang in my first comment. Click on it, and read JohnRennie's excellent answer.

Comment: I must say that her answer was excellent , therefore I'm sorry for my mistake as I'm just a beginner and thank's for making me realize my mistake.